# How to calculate net force from a Lorentz Force Density in Magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

Consider a pair of solenoid magnets as shown in the figure. Based on the magnetic field at each point(**B**) and corresponding Current Density, (**J**), I can calculate the Lorentz Force density at each point as 
**F** = **J** x **B**. Since it is a solenoid, if I consider, say YZ plane, I can get axial force density as 
**Fz** = **Jx** * **By**
and radial force density as
**Fy** = **Jx** * **Bz** for each discrete point in the coil.

From this Force density map, how can one calculate the net force in each solenoid? My intuition was adding all the values in a face, and multiplying it with the area of the face will give the force in that face. If it is correct, how do I find the net force in the body? multiply it by 2 *pi*?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had considered a standard solenoid from literature, where the final value from is known. The force density at different points was calculated and I could find out the method to correctly evaluate the net force.

If you have data at **N** points, your total area is **A**, **R** is the average radius, **r** is the radius at a given point, the net force can be given as,

$$ F =( \Sigma f ) \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \cdot R \cdot \frac{A}{N}  $$

A bit more accuracy can be gained by

$$ F = \Sigma (f \cdot r) \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{A}{N} $$